# No of Records inserted through Kafka to target snowflake vai kafka-snowflake connector are less as compared to source, mismatch in records

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I am using Snowflake-Kafka Connector. Where with 3 Kafka Servers Cluster are integrated. And this has a distributed connector executing above the Zookeeper and Kafka Services. And above all the Snowflake connector is running.
However the no of records as compared to source system the records are less in the target database Snowflake. How do I can get the accurate no of results and how do I can check for these records in Kafka as well as in Snowflake. Please help with concrete mechanism and steps/methods for the same.

Comment: Are there duplicate records on the source?

Comment: no there are no duplicates at source end

Answer (score 0):

The Number of records on snowflake side would only be less in case there are certain records that did not ingest.
You can check the COPY History table and also see [Table Stage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-create-stage.html#table-stages) if there are any files that have moved into this stage because the file could not be ingested.
You can capture a Debug log from the Kafka Connect and upload here

Please provide the Schema and table name as well.

Troubleshooting Kakfa Connector
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-ts.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. Its very easy to say go and capture things by enabling DEBUG. But what needs to be checked in DEBUG for the records not getting into target is not there. And regarding staging tables, these are created automatic. What needs to be checked here as the records which come into stage, will come to target.

Answer (score 0):

We face similar issue and it seems, it is associated with missing `consumer.auto.offset.reset=latest` configuration in connect-distributed.properties or connect-standalone.properties

Comment: `consumer.auto.offset.reset=latest` is the default config. It doesn't need to be explicitly set

Comment: Actually we were missing the config and that was causing some issue. Apart from that Snowflake kafka connector only supports Kafka 2.x versions and we were using 1.1.1 and that was causing issues too .. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-install.html#installation-prerequisites. Anytime we see "Resetting offset for partition" in logs we were missing records. Upgrading to 2.x resolved most of the offset resets but at random interval of around 8 hrs, it was still happening

Comment: Finally we were able to fix this issue. We observed that our Kafka log retention bytes was set to 3GB though the log retention hours were 144. We were easily hitting 3GB per partition and Kafka was deleting the oldest record even before it was consumed causing a mismatch in the offset values. We updated value based on our traffic and offset reset stopped thus stopping data loss.